# Android Firebase DataSnapshot class returning null to custom java object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing `Firebase` and `DataSnapshot` return null to custom java object.  I have try to solved this issue by following some answer using this site also but I don't know where is exact issue in my code.
Here I am attaching my `screenshot` of `firebase database` so kindly help me resolve this issue [image]

Below is my `model`.

```
        public class ChatModel {

    private String messege;
    private String user;
    private int intType;

    public ChatModel(){}

    public ChatModel(String messege, String user, int intType) {
        this.messege = messege;
        this.user = user;
        this.intType = intType;
    }


    public String getMessege() {
        return messege;
    }

    public void setMessege(String messege) {
        this.messege = messege;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getIntType() {
        return intType;
    }

    public void setIntType(int intType) {
        this.intType = intType;
    }
}
```

and here is my `activity`code.

```
DatabaseReference messagesReference = reference1.child("messages/"+ UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
        Log.e("messages URL "," ==>"+messagesReference);

            messagesReference .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Log.e("messages Referencev "," ==>"+dataSnapshot.toString());

                ChatModel map = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
                String message = map.getMessege();
                String userName = map.getUser();

                Log.e("message ","  ==>"+message);  // Here I am getting null value

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and `logcat` show message like this.
 ==>DataSnapshot { key = -KslrqBPRMNKkWQO15h_, value = {message=Hi This is sakib, user=sakib} }

Comment: In my code `message` variable returning null value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **keys are mismatch** that's why it's returning null value check your screenshot and your ChatModel class, remove `str` from your ChatModel class variables, and generate getter setter again

**This might help you.**

```
public class ChatModel {

  private String messege;
  private String user;
  private int intType;
  // TODO generate getter setter again
}
```

either you can get values via map as well

```
Map<String,String> map=(Map<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
String message = map.get("message");
String userName = map.get("user");
Log.e("message ","  ==>"+message);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for help me but it show error like ***DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type firebasechat.com.firebasechat.Model.ChatModel***

Comment: @SakibSyed i made the changes in my answer try now

Comment: @SakibSyed did you try?

Comment: I have just update my `model` into my project as well as here also but not working.

Comment: Error is still showing like ***E/message:   ==>null***

Comment: @SakibSyed can you post your `ChildEventListener` updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153443/discussion-between-sakib-syed-and-akhilesh0707).

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your model

```
private String message;
public String getMessage(){ return message;}
```

i had the same issue and it worked after i named the properties exactly like they are named in the firebase Database.

Comment: @ Ben Denger I have just rename ***message*** into model but still it is showing that ***E/message:   ==>null*** into `logcat`

Comment: isnt there a child missing? you are adding a listener for the node "sakib_testing", i think you have to iterate the Datasnapshot.getchildren() and then convert it to the chatmodel object

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in the for loop, like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

  if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

     for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

         ChatModel map = snapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);

         String message = map.getMessege();

         String userName = map.getUser();

     }
  }
```